# How to access Script Tag Variables From a Website using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am writting a web crawler and I need to extract following data from a web page.I have added the page source for your reference and  I want to access highlighted data. how can i do using python?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://pastebin.com/ewAn58Zt) might help you?